# Rolling a die that follows a poisson distribution and computing it's mean

Tags: probability-distributions

Roll a fair, 4-sided die N times where N is a Poisson random variable with parameter λ>0, let X be the number of 3's rolled in this experiment. Find E(x)

What I have figured out is that E(X) seems to be N/4. But am doubting this since we have been given the factor of Poisson.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the conditional expectation $\mathbb E[X \mid N=n] = n/4$.

Comment: How do I now incorporate Poisson distribution into this. I have been thinking of N/4 but by the fact that it is Poisson am confused

Comment: $\mathbb E[X] = \mathbb E[\mathbb E[X \mid N]]$.  What is $\mathbb E[N/4]$ if $N$ has a Poisson distribution?